# How to find a value in the row above OR two rows above?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula in excel that finds the row above a row that contains the word `Response`, and returns a number if that row contains `_exp_`.

Now I have found cases in which there is a row inbetween the rows containing `Response` and `_exp_`, so my formula needs to be updated such that it looks for `_exp_` both in the row above the one containing `Response` AND the row above that one.

This is the formula that is currently working well for cases where there is no "inbetween" row (basically it looks for Response in `row 121` and for `_exp_` in `row 120`:

```
=IF(AND(C121="Response";ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_exp_";D120)));MAX(N$5:N120)+1;"-")
```

I have tried to modify this code to look in two rows above by writing `D119:D120` instead of just `D120`, but it does not work. There is no error message but if just gives me the "-" meaning the `_exp_` is not there. This is how I did it:

```
=IF(AND(C121="Response";ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_exp_";D119:D120)));MAX(N$5:N120)+1;"-")
```

How do I change this code in order to make it look in the two rows above, instead of just 1? In other words: is there a way to say "check for `_exp_` in `D119` OR `D120`?"

I expect to get a value returned if `_exp_` appears in either of the two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=IF(AND(C121="Response";OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_exp_";D119));ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_exp_";D120))));MAX(N$5:N120)+1;"-")
```